# Why does typed/racket seem to insist that equal-hash-code returns Integer?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to port some plain racket code to typed/racket (6.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.5).  One of the problems encountered so far is that the type that `equal-hash-code` returns is `Integer` although the documentation claims `fixnum?`.  Indeed, `fixnum?` reports `#t` when given the result of `(equal-hash-code #"somebytes")`, but the type is `Integer`.  Thus, when I try to store the hash-code as a typed `Fixnum`, I get an error.  The code,

```
(define: foo : Fixnum (equal-hash-code #"somebytes"))
```

triggers the error in question.  Casting the result of `equal-hash-code` to `Fixnum` takes care of the error, but that suggests I'll need to perform this cast every time I compute a hash-code.  (In addition, the cast value still reports to be `- : Integer [more precisely: Fixnum]` for whatever that's worth.)

I'm concerned I'm missing something basic.  It seems odd that a function promising to return a fixnum should require its result to be cast to a fixnum.

Comment: Question: does the result *need* to be stored as a Fixnum, or can you just use Integers?

Comment: I think this is just a bug. I've fixed it in git: https://github.com/plt/racket/commit/0a71fe1d289938cde3e82df97ca199e655e1e237 Thanks for finding it!

Answer (score 1):

From some digging around in [the Typed Racket source](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/99c8da4d92259251c6fbdac38969c16dec80ef62/pkgs/typed-racket-pkgs/typed-racket-lib/typed-racket/base-env/base-env.rkt):

```
[equal-hash-code (-poly (a) (-> a -Integer))]
```

So, the documentation is lying about the current behavior. I think it's worth opening an issue about.

---

To expand upon my comment, do you need to use Fixnums? Since they're just a more specific type of Integer (putting this image here even if you already know this):

[image: Typed Racket Integer type breakdown]

I imagine you can just get away with using Integers.